# Feather M0 RFM69 serial over radio IP over serial works for UDP packets but fails for TCP sessions

Tags: c++, networking, feather

I'm trying to build a serial over radio transmitter module using two Feather M0 boards with RFM69HCW chips on board. As a test I'm trying to run a `slip` IP over serial session. This seems to work consistantly for UDP sessions (in my case ICMP ping requests) but fails for TCP sessions (in my case a simple HTTP request).

Here is the code:

```
#include <RFM69.h>
#include <RFM69_ATC.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string>
// a simple off the shelf CRC8 implementation
#include <crc.h>

// defined for one of the two boards
// #define B

#ifdef B
#define NODEID 1
#define RECEIVER 2
#endif
#ifndef B
#define NODEID 2
#define RECEIVER 1
#endif

#define MAX_BYTES 56

#define NETWORKID 100
#define FREQUENCY RF69_433MHZ
#define IS_RFM69HW_HCW

RFM69_ATC radio(8, 3, true);

char buf[512];

void setup()
{
  // initialize random using receiver address
  // this guarantees that both nodes have different initial random values
  randomSeed(RECEIVER);

  Serial.begin(115200);

  radio.initialize(FREQUENCY, NODEID, NETWORKID);
  radio.setPowerLevel(0);
  radio.setFrequency(446000000);
}

int8_t receiver_last_id = -1;

bool read_packet(bool override = false)
{
  if (radio.receiveDone() || override)
  {
    int cnt = radio.DATALEN - 2;
    int crc = radio.DATA[0];
    int8_t packet_id = radio.DATA[1];

    memcpy(buf, radio.DATA + 2, cnt);
    
    uint8_t crc_data = crc8(0, (uint8_t*)buf, cnt);

    if (radio.ACKRequested())
    {
      if (crc == crc_data)
      {
        radio.sendACK();
        
        // sometimes duplicates seem to occure
        // in case this happens just ignore the packet
        if (packet_id != receiver_last_id)
        {
          Serial.write(buf, cnt);
          receiver_last_id = packet_id;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        radio.ACK_REQUESTED = 0;
        return false;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

int8_t sender_packet_id = 0;

bool send_packet()
{
  int serial_cnt = Serial.available();

  if (serial_cnt > 0 && radio.canSend())
  {
    // packet structure:
    // 1. byte: CRC8 of DATA
    // 2. byte: ID of packet (to prevent duplicates)
    // variable length: DATA

    int payload_size = min(MAX_BYTES, serial_cnt);
    int total_size = payload_size + 2;

    Serial.readBytes((char *)buf + 2, payload_size);
    buf[0] = crc8(0, (uint8_t*)(buf + 2), payload_size);
    buf[1] = sender_packet_id++;

    while (!radio.sendWithRetry(RECEIVER, buf, total_size, 1, 5U))
    {
      // radio.receiveDone() switches the
      // radio into receive mode
      if (radio.receiveDone())
      {
        // if receive is done instantly
        // process the packet and move on
        read_packet(true);
        continue;
      }

      // wait random time in case
      // a collision happened
      delay(random(5, 30));

      read_packet();

      // wait for radio to be ready to send
      while (!radio.canSend()) ;
    }

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

void loop()
{
  read_packet();

  send_packet();
}
```

I also have a network capture of both sides.

Here is the capture for the Client: https://ufile.io/v945jl8i

Here is the capture for the Server: https://ufile.io/yn36rjw4

I've figured out that it happens somewhere in the `while (!radio.sendWithRetry(RECEIVER, buf, total_size, 1, 5U))` loop but I can't figure out what exactly goes wrong and how I can fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I'm running a simple python HTTP server (`python 3 -m http.server 8080`). And as client i'm using curl (`curl <server address>:8080`)

Here are the Commands I use for starting slip:

```bash
modprobe slip
slattach -vL -s 115200 -p slip /dev/ttyACM0
ifconfig sl0 192.168.2.1 pointtopoint 192.168.2.2 up
```

I switched the two IP addresses for the other side.

Also interestingly it sometimes seems to randomly work for one or two requests, so i'm guessing some kind of race condition.

I also made sure that i'm connecting to the correct serial ports.

PS: i'm kind of new to C++ so any recommendations on best practices are also appreciated

Comment: Are you running an actual server on the receiver?

Comment: edited the question to add the info. TLDR: yes, I have a server running